# Translate a docker run command into docker SDK code for Golang

Tags: docker, go, sdk, containers, docker-container

I'm pretty new to Docker and Docker Engine SDKs. Currently I'm working on creating a library to run Docker containers in the background using Go client for the Docker Engine API (SDK). I'm not sure how to write the code doing the same work with certain commands.

For example 
`/usr/local/bin/docker run --network=host --rm -i -v /path_to_project:/src -v /.../go/pkg:/go/pkg imageName yamllint -d .yamllint .`

Here's the current code I've written in my main package

```
resp, err := cli.ContainerCreate(ctx, &container.Config{
        Image: imageName,
        Cmd:   []string{"yamllint", "-d" ,".yamllintls"},
    }, &container.HostConfig{
        NetworkMode: "host",
        Mounts: []mount.Mount{
            {
                Type:   mount.TypeBind,
                Source: "/path_to_project",
                Target: "/src",
            },},
    }, nil, nil, "myContainer")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    if err := cli.ContainerStart(ctx, resp.ID, types.ContainerStartOptions{}); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
```

I don't know if this is correct and which functions/ parameters I should use to specific some flags like `--rm`, `-i`, `-verbose`, etc.

Comment: [`--rm` is in HostConfig](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/docker/docker@v24.0.5+incompatible/api/types/container#HostConfig) .  `-i` I think is equivalent to the AttachStdin, AttachStdout, AttachStderr.  `--verbose` is irrelevant in this usage; instead you can print `err` to user as you choose.